# Solving modular equations that gives GCD = 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have problems with understanding modular equations that gives GCD = 1. For example:

$$3x \equiv 59 \mod 100$$

So I'm getting $GCD(3, 100) = 1$. Now:

$1 = -33*3 + 100$

That's where the first question appears - I always guess those -33 and 1 (here) numbers...is there a way to solve them?

And the second question - the answer to that equation, at least according to the book, is:

{$-33*59 + 100k$} (k - integer) - and why is that so? Where did the 59 came from?

Comment: The $59$ comes from the $59$ in $3x \equiv 59$. You just multiply both sides by $-33$...

Comment: $\gcd(59,100)=1~~\Rightarrow~~ 59a+100b=1$
$$3(59a+100b)x = 59(mod~{100})\\
59\cdot(3ax-1) = 0(mod~{100})\\
3ax = 1(mod~{100})\\$$
In your case $a=39$, so
$$117x = 1(mod~{100})\\
17x = 1(mod~{100})$$
Esing EGCD again, you find $x,y$ that $17x+100y=1$. That x is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, $3x=59+100y$ where $y$ is an integer

$\implies 3x=100y+59(100-3\cdot33)$

$\implies 3(x+59\cdot 33)=100(y+59)$

$\implies \frac{3(x+59\cdot 33)}{100}=y+59$ which is an integer

$\implies 100$ divides $3(x+59\cdot 33)$

$\implies 100$ divides $(x+59\cdot 33)$ as $(3,100)=1$

So, $x+59\cdot 33=100\cdot k$ where $k$ is an integer

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{eqnarray} \text{Note} &&\ 1 &=&\ 3\, (-33)\ \ \ \, +\ \ \ \, 100\, (1)  \\
 \stackrel{\times\, 59\ }\Rightarrow && 59\, &=&\ 3\, (-33\cdot 59) + 100\, (59)\end{eqnarray}$$

Hence $\ 59 = 3x+100y \ $ has a *particular* solution $\rm\:(x,y) = (-33\cdot 59, 59).\, $ By *linearity*, the general solution is the sum of this and the solution of the associated *homogeneous* equation $\ 0 = 3x+100y,\,$ so $\, 
\frac{y}x = \frac{-3}{100},\ $ so $\ x = 100k,\ y = -3k .\,$ So the general solution is their sum  $$(-33\cdot 59,\,59)\, +\, (100k, -3k)\, =\, (-33\cdot 59+100k,\, 59-3k)$$